# Saving in XML only last object from the list

Tags: c#, xml

Could you please tell me how can I fix my code? I tried a lot of ways, for example with XmlSerializer, but still nothing. 
The code always saving the last item of the list, and I have no idea how to fix it.
The code:

```
 foreach (ObservableCollection<Person> x in list)
            {

                XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
                     new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                     new XElement("Person",
                     from person in x
                     select new XElement("Person",
                         new XElement("Name", person.Name),
                         new XElement("Surname", person.Surname),
                         new XElement("Age", person.Age))));
                xdoc.Save(path);
            }
```

I would be greatful for any tip!

Comment: what type is `list` ?  the `from image select` does not make sense, could you make sure you posted an example that compiles ?

Comment: I had my own code earlier, but it was not understandable so I changed it to a more transparent example.

So there should be "select from the person"
Type of the person:
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Person>> list

Comment: `xdoc.Save(path)`. If path is same, it will keep overwriting old file. So if last `ObservableCollection<Person>` in `list` is having only one element you will see only last item in the file.

Answer (score 2):

from the comments I understood you have a list of lists and you want to flatten it in the resulting XML. You could use this:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("Persons",
            from x in list
            from person in x
            select new XElement("Person",
            new XElement("Name", person.Name),
            new XElement("Surname", person.Surname),
            new XElement("Age", person.Age))));

xdoc.Save("tmp.xml");
```

Your solution did not work because you saved the XML document in each iteration of the `foreach` loop, which would overwrite the existing file, so the result would have been only the last iteration of the loop

Comment: Yep! Now it works, thank you a lot.
I know that, but i didn't know how to fix it.
Once again - thanks!

Comment: @Elgahir glad to help, don't forget to mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

He is a slightly different xml linq solution :

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
                     new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                     new XElement("People"));
XElement people = xdoc.Root;
foreach (ObservableCollection<Person> x in list)
{

   XElement person =  new XElement("Person", fom person in x
      select new XElement("Person",
         new XElement("Name", person.Name),
         new XElement("Surname", person.Surname),
         new XElement("Age", person.Age)));
   people.Add(person);
}
xdoc.Save(path);
```